# Network errors in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am a newbie to iOS and using Alamofire in my app. Everything is working fine. Now I want to implement network errors. I have searched about it and here are my findings:

We can implment request timed out in the following way:

```
       let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
       manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10

        let urlVerifyEmail = ####
        manager.request(urlVerifyEmail, method: .post, parameters: ["user_email" : email],    encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

               print (“success”)

            case .failure(let serverError):

                if (serverError._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
                {
                    print(”Request timed out”)
                }
                else
                {
                    print(”Error sending request to server”)

                }
            }
        }
        )
```

I have read there official docs too. However I am not having much clarity. 
What does request timed out actually mean? Does it mean that the app is taking too long to send the request? or server is taking too long to send the response back?

What are other types or network errors in Alamofire? What if the connection wasn't successfully made? What if it broke while the request was getting sent? What if it broke while the response was coming back?

If error code for request timed out is -1001 then what are the codes for other network errors? In order to provide the users with the best experience, which is the best approach to cover all of network errors?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror/1448136-nserror_codes

Comment: This will provide you all the errors related to Http requests.